# Setting DigitsKeyListener

Tags: android

I am trying to assign a nummeric input type based on the comma as a decimal point, as the german locale uses comma as decimal point as follows in the TextChangeListener:

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789,"));
```

However, using stock Samsung Keyboard (Note 10.1 N8000) and stock LG Keyboard (LG G3) forces a number keypad forcing entering only numbers from 0-9 without any possible decimals. Running a third party keyboard like SwiftKey and Google Keyboard displays a fully nummeric keypad inlcuding a decimal and a comma.
Any idea about how to solve the problem with stock keyboards?

---

**My XML file:**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInfoUltiva"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ultiva_info"
            android:textSize="9pt" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUltivaSepLine"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtInfoUltiva"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtInfoUltiva"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gpGewichtUltiva"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textUltivaSepLine"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textUltivaSepLine"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblGewichtUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/lbl_gewicht_ultiva"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtGewichtUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="@string/txt_hint_gewicht_ultiva"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:digits="0123456789," />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gpKonzentrationUltiva"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gpGewichtUltiva"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gpGewichtUltiva"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblKonzentrationUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/lbl_konzentration_ultiva"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/txtKonzentrationUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="@string/txt_hint_konzentration_ultiva"
                android:entries="@array/ultiva_konzentrationen" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gpGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gpKonzentrationUltiva"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gpKonzentrationUltiva"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/lbl_geschwindigkeit_ultiva"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txtGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:hint="@string/txt_hint_geschwindigkeit_ultiva"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUltivaSep1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gpGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gpGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gpgemesseneGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textUltivaSep1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textUltivaSep1"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblgemesseneGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/lbl_gemessene_geschwindigkeit_ultiva"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtgemesseneGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:hint="@string/txt_hint_gemessene_geschwindigkeit_ultiva" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gpEntleerungszeitUltiva"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gpgemesseneGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gpgemesseneGeschwindigkeitUltiva"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lblEntleerungszeitUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:text="@string/lbl_entleerungszeit_ultiva"
                android:textSize="8pt" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtEntleerungszeitUltiva"
                android:layout_width="0.0dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1.5"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:textSize="8pt"
                android:hint="@string/txt_hint_entleerungszeit_ultiva" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textUltivaSep2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/gpEntleerungszeitUltiva"
            android:layout_below="@+id/gpEntleerungszeitUltiva"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="#000000" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbUltivaNutzungInfo"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textUltivaSep2"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textUltivaSep2"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:text="@string/ultiva_nutzung_info"
            android:textSize="5pt" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: can you please post your XML file? This post might help you.
http://www.androidcentral.com/how-add-dedicated-number-row-google-keyboard

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this.  A Listener does not set the keys.  The keyboard app itself decides this.  A Listener only disallows certain characters, it does NOT do anything with the keyboard or control the keys the keyboard wishes to display.  Your inputType is used by the keyboard as a hint for that, but your keyboard won't even know what a KeyListener is, much less that one is applied.

Comment: The listener provides an InputType, which overrides what has been previously been set as the inputType on the EditText.  

The KeyListener should be wrapped in one that provides the correct input type to get the desired behavior on Samsung